# What happens to the main thread in this case

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have the following multithreaded program:

```
class Program{
  static void main(){
    (new Thread(DoSomething)).Start();
  }
  static void DoSomething(){
    // Dome something here...
  }
}
```

A couple of questions:

1. Does the main thread exit after spinning off the child thread?
2. If it does exit and the child thread is a background thread: Is the main process going to exit or will it wait for the background thread to finish?

Comment: Add `Console.Write` and see for yourself

Comment: Question #2 is a bit redundant. You first ask if it's just going to exit and then you ask that if it does exit: "does it exit" or "does it wait"? Well if it exits, then it exits.

Comment: @jlafay There is a difference whether the child thread is a background one or not :) and hence the question

Comment: There is no difference to the main thread. It will exit regardless.

Comment: The main thread might exit regardless, but the process will not exit immediately if the thread is foreground. You can quickly run the code I posted in my answer below to prove this to yourself. He specified "process", not "thread" in his second question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically, if you want to wait for the child thread to complete, you'd add a `x.Join();` line (where x is the variable of your thread) wherever you want your main thread to stop and wait for the child to complete.

EDIT: So, yes, the main thread will exit unless one of three cases occurs:
a) the spawned thread completes before the rest of the main thread code (if you add any)

b) You have a condition that waits for the thread to complete (such as the Join statement I mentioned, but there are other ways too).

c) The main thread goes into a semi-infinite loop (such as a game/graphics engine).

In your bare-bones example, it will exit for sure (given your question's parameters, a background thread).

EDIT2: Sorry, I seem to have dodged your second question (and actually only considered background threads the whole while). If it's a background thread it will exit as I've explained, if it's foreground then it shouldn't (though I don't have much experience with foreground threads, so I can't say for sure).

So to answer your questions: Yes, the main thread exits. Yes, if the child is specifically a background thread, the process will exit as well.

EDIT3: Final edit, I promise. I just wanted to add some code so that you could prove the answer yourself (which is always nice to be able to do):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Thread thready = new Thread(DoSomething);
    thready.IsBackground = true;
    thready.Start();
}

static void DoSomething()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write("thread's looping \n");
    }
}
```

By toggling the `thready.IsBackground = true;`  to `thready.IsBackground = false;` you get a program that runs forever (not exiting until the thread does). Leaving it as true will exit very quickly.

Answer (score 7):

"By default, threads you create explicitly are foreground threads. Foreground threads keep the application alive for as long as any one of them is running, whereas background threads do not. Once all foreground threads finish, the application ends, and any background threads still running abruptly terminate.

```
class PriorityTest
{
    static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        Thread worker = new Thread ( () => Console.ReadLine() );
        if (args.Length > 0) worker.IsBackground = true;
        worker.Start();
    }
}
```

If this program is called without any arguments, the worker thread will take foreground status and will wait on the ReadLine statement for the user to press Enter. Simultaniously, the main thread exits, but the application keeps running because a foreground thread is still alive.

However, if an argument is passed to Main(), the worker is assigned background status, and the program exits almost immediately as the main thread ends (terminating the ReadLine and the program)."

See [Joseph Albahri's (a genius and great guy) page](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) on threading for more information (it is where this was extracted from).

Answer (score 6):

Depends on [Thread.IsBackground](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx).

The process will not exit before all the foreground threads finish. In the following example...

```
class Program {

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        (new Thread(DoSomething)).Start();
    }

    static void DoSomething() {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }

}
```

...the process will exit after 5 seconds.

But in this example...

```
class Program {

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        (new Thread(DoSomething) { IsBackground = true }).Start();
    }

    static void DoSomething() {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }

}
```

...the process will exit (almost) immediately. The effect on the child background thread that is still running is similar to forcibly killing the process, so avoid doing that if possible.

Answer (score 1):

main process thread will definitely exit...

edit: i rechecked the docs and found that IsBackground property is false by default...which means the main thread will wait...the earlier response ws with regards to the 2nd question

Comment: Why? It will be automatically created as a foreground thread, this concequently will cause the parent/main thread to wait until it has done its work...